# What are Fuel Cells used for?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

What are the Fuel Cells used for in Metal Gear Rising? I see it under my health bar and I see it deplete but I don't know it's purpose. I'm also new to the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fuel cell is used for blade mode (default L1), when you enter blade mode you will see the meter start depleting. When it is empty, blade mode will lose its slow-motion effect and you will no longer be able to cut enemies. You can regain fuel cell by attacking or performing zandatsus.

Metal Gear Rising is a offshot of the Metal Gear Solid series, while there are references to previous games the game plays very differently and is fine to play as a standalone title.